# how to echo out search results to another page

Tags: php, search

@Evan trying to echo out 0 results on to the newpage.php also how can i define the $searchQuery from newpage.php... it seems like i have to rewrite all of the code onto the newpage.php ... is there a way to just to form action to another page?

```
    <?php

session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

include_once("db_connects.php");

$queryArray = array();
$goodQuery = true;
$search_output = "";

if(isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != ""){
    $searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
{
    $sqlCommand = "(SELECT id, links, page_body, page_title AS title FROM pages WHERE MATCH (page_title,page_body) AGAINST ('$searchquery'))";
} 

$query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($count > 1){

    $search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $queryArray[] = $row;
    } 
}
else {
     $goodQuery = false;
     $_SESSION['error'] = true;
     header("Location: newpage.php");

}

if($goodQuery){

    $_SESSION['search_output'] = $queryArray;
    header("Location: newpage.php");

    exit;
}
else{
    echo $search_output;
}
}
  ?>
```

This is the code on the newpage.php once it is header away..

```
 <?php

session_start(); 

if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){

     $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";

    } else {

    foreach($_SESSION['search_output'] as $value){
        $value['links'];
        $value['title'];
        $value['page_body'];


        $title = $value['title'];
        $link = $value['links'];
        $body = $value['page_body'];

        $search_output .= "<a href='".$link."'>".$title."</a> - $body<br>";
}
}
?>

<div>
<?php echo $search_output; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to store the query results in an `array`. Once you have done that you can use `header` in `php` to bring the user to a new page. Once the user is on the new page you can `echo` back the results of the query (which is now stored in the `$_SESSION`):

**First, create an array:**

```
$queryArray = array();
```

**Second, query the database and store each row in the array we just created**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

       $queryArray[] = $row;


        } // close while
```

**Third, move the array to the SESSION variable:**

```
$_SESSION['search_output'] = $queryArray;
```

**Fourth, move the user to the new page:**

```
header("Location: newpage.php");
```

**Lastly, echo out your data:**

```
foreach($_SESSION['search_output'] as $value){
    echo $value;
}
```

**EDIT: Update with full code:**

```
    <?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

include_once("db_connects.php");

$queryArray = array();
$goodQuery = true;
$search_output = "";

if(isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != ""){
    $searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
    $sqlCommand = "(SELECT id, links, page_body, page_title AS title FROM pages WHERE MATCH      enter code here(page_title,page_body) AGAINST ('$searchquery'))";
} 

$query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count > 1){
    $search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $queryArray[] = $row;
    } 
}
else {
    $goodQuery = false;
    $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";
}

if($goodQuery){
    $_SESSION['search_output'] = $queryArray;
    header("Location: newpage.php");
    exit;
}
else{
    echo $search_output;
}

  ?>
```

**Now, on the newpage.php:**

You now need to get the results from your query (which are stored in the SESSION). You can do this by looping through the SESSION:

```
session_start(); // Make sure you add this at the top of the page 

foreach($_SESSION['search_output'] as $value){
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: i am not quite sure what you mean... i am new to php... would i remove the else statement?

Comment: @arianna Let me know which part is confusing you and I'll address it when I wake up

Comment: it is redirecting to the 'newpage.php' but its showing Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in \newpage.php on line 1

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in \newpage.php on line 1

Comment: you need to add `session_start` to the top of *every* page that you're using `SESSSION` on

Comment: you must be really annoyed with me im sorry.. but its showing Notice: Undefined index: search_output in \newpage.php on line 5

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in \newpage.php on line 5 I have updated my code (look above)

Comment: @arianna Are you *sure* you have `session_start` on the ***first*** page too?

Comment: yes i just added it in now only the Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in \newpage.php on line 5 is showing

Comment: @arianna above the `foreach` do a `print_r($_SESSION['search_output'])` and tell me what is displayed :)

Comment: it displays the number of results and the search word i typed in .. followed by the same warning

Comment: @arianna Well you can remove the `print_r` line now - If the results are showing then it seems to be working. You just need to use the `foreach` to loop through the array as shown above, and then you would do whatever you were doing before with each `row`  - remember, `row` represents the query row from before, so you would need to do `$value['some_column']` :)

Comment: i love you thanks for your help it works! just one last thing, how would i get the results to show on the newpage if its 0. its still showing on the same page

Comment: You would set another $_SESSION variable called "error" and then set the error message in the same `search_output` SESSION value. So now on the new page you would first check `if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){// error code here} else{// normal query code here}

Comment: when setting the $_session['error'] what do i make it = too? I have else {
     $goodQuery = false;
     $_SESSION['error'] = $goodQuery;
 
 
} but it seems now that $_SESSION is always false